# How to automatically refresh strings obtained from NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxmlparser

I have successfully created a Cocoa app that uses NSXMLParser to retrieve data from an online XML file. Now I am trying to figure out how to automatically refresh the XML data.

Here are some of the relevant methods in my implementation file:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my_url_here"];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
}
```

So how can I automatically refresh the XML every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out NSTimer with a repeating interval

Example to call a method called getMessage every 15 minutes (900 seconds):

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:900
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(getMessage:)
                                                userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

self.repeatingTimer = timer;
```

[Timer Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000061i)

Comment: Yes, the NSTimer approach is what I'm looking for. Works great. Thanks!